# Javascript get information from id

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

SO I have this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<products>
<product top-level-category="cat" sub-level-category="cat-sub">
    <id>235</id>
    <title>title</title>
    <brand>brand 1</brand>
    <price>200.00</price>
    <description>This is my amazing description</description>
    <spec>
        <s1>24.2</s1>
        <s2>23.5 x 15.6 CMOS</s2>
        <s3>Auto, 100-12800</s3>
        <s4>Nikon F Mount</s4>
    </spec>
</product>
<products>
```

How would I get the title, brand, price, s1, s2, s3, s4, etc by just having the ID of the product?

My current failed attempt:

```
$(productsDomTree).each(function() {
                    var name = $(this).find('id').text();

                    if (name = vars['id']) {
                        alert(name);
                    }
                });
```

All this does is tell me that it found the correct element

Updated code that works, but always selects the second one:

```
var id = vars['id'];
                alert(id);
                var ids = ($products).find('id');
                var id = ids.filter(function(id) { return !!$(this).text() == id; });
                var product = id.parent();
                var title = product.find( "title" ).text();
                alert(title);
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. We love to help you but we want to see your own approach. Show us your code where you try to read this data.

Comment: @JakubKriz Currently editing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done if you feed the xml string into jQuery's parseXML function:

```
var id = 235;
var xml = "Your XML Here!";
var xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml );
var $xml = $( xmlDoc );
var ids = $xml.find('id');
var id = ids.filter(function(id) { return !!$(this).text() == id; });
var product = id.parent();
var title = product.find( "title" ).text();
```

Comment: And? where is the ID?

Comment: Now I see what you were saying. My answer has been edited to include an example ID.

Comment: So here is what I have:
`var id = vars['id'];
    var ids = $products.find('id');
    var id = ids.filter(function(id) { return $(this).text() == id; });
    var product = id.parent();
    var title = product.find( "title" ).text();

    alert(title);`

and it shows up nothing.

Comment: Did you parse the xml with $($.parseXML(xml))?

Comment: @oMiKeY I did, All I get from Edge is "The site says..." and nothing.

Comment: @oMiKeY any ideas?

Comment: I would alert after every line if no other debug options are available. Example: var id = vars['id']; =>  alert(id); => var ids = $products.find('id'); => alert(ids.toString()); => etc

Comment: Hmmm, also instead of "return $(this).text() == id;" it may have to be "return !!$(this).text() == id;" because the text of the xml needs to be converted to an integer, !! before "a number" is a little shortcut for parseInt("a number")

Comment: @oMiKeY everything looks fine up until we get to the product.find

Comment: @oMiKeY that was it! the "return !!$(this).text() == id;" Thank you so much, can you please update your code?

Comment: @oMiKeY just realized, it is ALWAYS selecting the product with the id of 0002

Comment: Could you update your code in the question? I might be able to figure it out.

Comment: @oMiKeY updated, the first alert for the id is correct, but the second alert for the title is always the same.

Comment: @oMiKeY I noticed with the exclamation marks if I have 1 then it always selects the first product, if I have 2 it always selects the second product

Answer (score 0):

CSS selectors can't access the text content of the elements. Then, I recommend XPath, e.g.

```js
var xmlString = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><products><product top-level-category="cat" sub-level-category="cat-sub"><id>235</id><title>title</title><brand>brand 1</brand><price>200.00</price><description>This is my amazing description</description><spec><s1>24.2</s1><s2>23.5 x 15.6 CMOS</s2><s3>Auto, 100-12800</s3><s4>Nikon F Mount</s4></spec></product></products>';
var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xmlString, "text/xml");
var iterator = doc.evaluate('//product[id = "235"]/*', doc, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
var obj = {}, val;
while (val = iterator.iterateNext())
  obj[val.nodeName] = val.textContent;
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Permission denied error: jquery-2.2.0.min.js (2,24762)

Comment: Strange, given that my code doesn't use jQuery at all.